# SOAPUI Testing error, test always fail with storage exception

Tags: mysql, soapui

Although I have the sql jar on my classpath, I'm still getting an error when I try to actually add a record. The stacktrace I'm running into is below

```
com.sample.reservation.exception.StorageException: Can not find the driver class

    at com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.getConnection(Storage.java:47 2)
    at com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.getRoomDetails(Storage.java:2 19)
    at com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.addRoom(Storage.java:78)
    at com.sample.reservation.RoomManagementService.addRoom(RoomManagementSe rvice.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl. java:62)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you may have a general SQL jar on the classpath, you're probably missing a jar that provides a driver for the *specific* database you're using (which you haven't specified). Most SQL engines are abstractions that can be extended to work around an individual database's particular aspects - you'll want to find the relevant one for your SQL engine and add that to your dependencies as well.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar is in classpath. should I use different one? perhaps I once put in all the available jars ..

Comment: @MalleswariCH you might find this document helpful on how to specifically tell your application to actually load the mysql JDBC driver - I believe just having it on the classpath may not be enough. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: I am able to connect to database fine manually from soapui, but this problem occuring when I try testing API for hotel reservation example. I wonder what I should be tweaking to get soapui tests get mysql connection. i can share the .aar file for checking if possible